# Hiding qTip On Element Click: Element Is on qTip from Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, qtip

On clicking a link, I show a qTip which gets its content from an ajax request.  The content contains a close button.  So I add this to my config...

```
hide: {
        when: {
            target: $('#closeBtn'),
            event: 'click'
        }
    }
```

However, it doesn't actually hide the qTip.  I suspect it is because the closeBtn doesn't yet exist when qTip is wired up.  I suspect I can do it manually in one of the API callbacks, but just thought I'd check here and see if anyone else can confirm this or point to something I've done incorrectly.

UPDATE: Adding some code in the onShow callback allows me to achieve what I want.  But I still think the hide configuration should work, at least in a future version.

Answer (score 3):

qTip2 comes with an option to apply a [close button to the tooltip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#tips), so you do not need to do it on your own.

```
title: {
   text: 'test'
   button: true
}
```

### Update

Since qtip2 got updates you define the close button like this

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I really like owls!',
        title: 'About me',
        button: 'Close'
    },
    hide: {
        event: false
    }
});
```

http://qtip2.com/options#content.button

Comment: can you please post some sample code as the code above doesn't work for me.